# Possibility of updating data in real-time on a client

Tags: websocket, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, analytics, real-time

I have the following scenario that I was wondering if it's possible/feasible to implement. I apologize if this is considered an overly "broad" question, but I think SO would be the best place to ask this.

Let us suppose I have a website and I want to display a graph to an end-user. For the purposes of this example, let's say we want to show them "Sales per category" in the past hour. The data would be displayed in a graph, and the SQL to run the query might be something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM sales 
WHERE timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
GROUP BY category
```

As far as I'm aware, there are two general ways to update the data for the end-user:

1. Do some sort of polling (or a similar technique) at a certain interval to re-fetch the data from the query. However, this can become quite expensive depending on the complexity/duration of the query and how many people are connected simultaneously.
2. The second method would be to store all the data in-memory and push the update directly to that memory store (which could be either client-side, or server side, and we could send a ws request to the end user whenever there's a data update. An example of this would be using something like https://github.com/jpmorganchase/perspective.

My question then is if it's possible at all do do real-time data updating (the case I describe in Example 2) when the data is too large to store in memory. I think the answer is a "no", but perhaps I'm missing some ways to do this. For example, let's say I have 1TB of data stored in BigQuery and I am streaming updates to it with new product purchases -- is there a way to push updates to the end-client without having to re-run the query for every time I want to get an update? Are there any other technologies that might be used/useful for this scenario?

Again, I don't think it's possible but wanted to see what's possible for as near-real-time display to an end-client as possible on a queried data set.

Comment: Hi David542, perhaps something like Google PubSub could work?  I.e. every time a new product is purchased a "message" containing pertinent information of the purchase is posted via the message publishing client in parallel to the database being updated.  The messages are received via a subscriber which processes them and compiles the information from the last (say) hours worth of messages into a format that is useful and presentable on a graph.  I know nothing about databases, FYI! More here: 
 https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview

Comment: @Paul -- right, we're currently using that, but my question would be how to update the end-user's graph with it?

Comment: What about webpush - https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-webpush-protocol-10? You could have a trigger done in the database that would fill a table on which you would have a client subscribtion, which would that push the change to the client.

Comment: @tukan how would that work with something like bigquery or another database exactly?

Comment: What about Cloud Firestore? You are already using pub/sub so you could create a cloud function to handle the message from pub/sub to update your Cloud Firestore Database.

Comment: I think there's an issue with the client's graph and it's design requirements... sales per hour is both lacking information and hard to update. Updates need to deduct sales (out-dates) as well as add new sales... I would consider a 24 hour graph, or a 12 hour graph divided by actual hours. This will simplify updates and provide more useful metrics. Updates will only need to add new sales (data is never stale) and the information is more actionable.

Comment: The solution is the same solution of real time messagging by using a real time DB? Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is unique per client, big and real-time changing, there is no salvation in using any database or cache as an exchange. You have to send the data update directly.

If you can't directly push data to the client from the process doing the database update, you probably can pass the data from the process doing the update to the process doing the pushes through a message broker (I'll use Rabbitmq as an example).

The optimal configuration for this setup is a [topic model](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html), where a topic is a client ID or key, and making one listener per connected client for that topic - alternatively, one listener for all clients, but registering/unregistering topics dynamically.

Have the websocket handler listen to the topic of their client. Setup the process updating the database to also stream updates to the topic id of the client. The broker will discard all updates not going to a connected client, making the load more manageable in the listener end.

Without any storage or polling, this solution is low latency. And even with a thousand simultaneous clients, I doubt the broker would ever exhaust memory.

Comment: thanks for this answer. Hmm...what would the above accomplish other than pushing the "query every 5s" from the client to the server? Either way you'd still be querying every 5s...

Comment: @David542 Querying once every 5s *per client* is very different than querying once every 5s *total*. The solutions i propose achieve the latter.

Comment: no, not necessarily. Either way we would make a request to our api, checksum the query, and if it's the same return the cached-query and if not, query our datastore and return the new query results. So in this sense, if there are 100 different queries among the clients (whether 100 clients or 10,000), querying once every 5 seconds would produce 20 queries per second. Or am I missing something in your answer?

Comment: @David542 It's lacking from your original post your data is unique per client. I assumed from the sample query it wasn't. Obviously, I know no way of generating 100 unique results from 100 unique datasets without running 100 unique queries. I will rewrite the answer with more relevant stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in this option I decided to extend the comment to an answer.  I will take the *SQL Server* and *C#* compoment - [sqltabledependency](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency).  You can check it out if it fits your needs.

1. You would create a temp table where you would put any changes from the `sales` table e.g. `sales_data_watch` (you could have there also the precalculation aggregations as in your example).
2. You would create a hourly job which would monitor the changes in the `sales` table and perform insert/updates on the `sales_data_watch`
3. You would have connected the C# sqltabledependency connected to `sales_data_watch` (note: taken from the example to fit your table)

   ```
   public class SaleData
   {
      public int revenue{ get; set; }
   }

   public class Program
   {
    private static string _con = "data source=.; initial catalog=MyDB; integrated security=True";

    public static void Main()
    {
     // The mapper object is used to map model properties 
     // that do not have a corresponding table column name.
     // In case all properties of your model have same name 
     // of table columns, you can avoid to use the mapper.
     var mapper = new ModelToTableMapper<SaleData>();
     mapper.AddMapping(s => s.revenue, "Aggregated revenue");

     // Here - as second parameter - we pass table name: 
     // this is necessary only if the model name is different from table name 
     // (in our case we have Sale vs Sales). 
     // If needed, you can also specifiy schema name.
     using (var dep = new SqlTableDependency<SaleData>(_con, "sales_data_watch", mapper: mapper));
     {
      dep.OnChanged += Changed;
      dep.Start();

      Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
      Console.ReadKey();

      dep.Stop();
     } 
    }

    public static void Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<SaleData> e)
    {
     var changedEntity = e.Entity;

     Console.WriteLine("DML operation: " + e.ChangeType);
     Console.WriteLine("Revenue: " + changedEntity.Revenue);
    }
   }
   ```
4. After all the notifications have been distributed you could do `truncate table sales_data_watch` after (if you don't want the table to grow too big which would slow down the whole process eventually.

This is using only sql server and C# component.  There are other, probably better options, for example: [Detect record table change with MVC, SignalR, jQuery and SqlTableDependency](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-mvc-signalR-jquery-sqltabledependency-example) to do it differently.  That will depend on your  preferences.

**Edit** a complete example link for [*Building real time charts with Angular 5, Google Charts, SignalR Core, .NET Core 2, Entity Framework Core 2 and SqlTable dependency*](http://anthonygiretti.com/2017/12/31/building-real-time-charts-with-angular-5-google-charts-signalr-core-net-core-2-entity-framework-core-2-and-sqltable-dependency-part-1/) (this link is first page of three).  At the top of the page you can see real-time google's gaugeschart.  All credits go to [anthonygiretti](http://anthonygiretti.com/author/anthonygiretti/).  You can download the example project at [github](https://github.com/AnthonyGiretti/Angular5-RealTime-gauges-with-SignalR-Core-EFCore2).

### Technologies used

Database

Sql Server, localDb with Visual Studio 2017 is correct to make it work

Front End technologies

```
Angular 5
Google Charts
Visual Studio Code
SignalR Client
```

BackEnd technologies

```
.NET Core 2
SignalR Core
EntityFramework Core
EntityFramework Core for Sql Server
SqlTableDependency
```

First is to install compoenents needed - service broker, SQL Table, Angular-CLI, Angular 5 project, SignalR client (VS 2017, .Net Core 2 SDK installed) - link is the same [part1](http://anthonygiretti.com/2017/12/31/building-real-time-charts-with-angular-5-google-charts-signalr-core-net-core-2-entity-framework-core-2-and-sqltable-dependency-part-1/)

Next comes the backend setup - [part2](http://anthonygiretti.com/2017/12/31/building-real-time-charts-with-angular-5-google-charts-signalr-core-net-core-2-entity-framework-core-2-and-sqltable-dependency-part-2/)

To make it work this project contains :

- A DbContext (GaugesContext.cs) for EntityFramework Core
- A Hub (GaugeHub.cs) for SignalR that broadcast data
- A Model that contains strongly typed data to send (Gauge.cs)
- A Repository exposed with Entity Framework and its Interface (GaugeRepository.cs and IGaugeRepository.cs)
- A Subscription to Gauge sql table with SqlTableDependency and its Interface (GaugeDatabaseSubscription.cs and IDatabaseSubscription)
- Two Extension methods that extends IServiceCollection (AddDbContextFactory.cs) and IApplicationBuilder (UseSqlTableDependency.cs)
  And Startup.cs and Program.cs

Last part is to setup the frontend - [part3](http://anthonygiretti.com/2017/12/31/building-real-time-charts-with-angular-5-google-charts-signalr-core-net-core-2-entity-framework-core-2-and-sqltable-dependency-part-3/)

We have :

- A folder that contains the gauge chart component (gaugeschart.component.html and gaugeschart.component.ts)
- A folder that contains a gauge chart service and a Google Charts base service (google-gauges-chart.service.ts and google-charts.base.service.ts)
- A folder that contains environments files
- A folder that contains a strongly typed model for the gauge chart (gauge.ts)
- Finally at the root of src folder the defaults files components and module (app component files and app module file)

In the next step you should test it to see if the data are projected into the graphs correctly when you changed the data.

Comment: still, this is to detect "record" changes, which isn't the issue. The issue would be that the user is looking at a graph with a sql query applied -- any 'record' changes would only be helpful in that they tell the client to "run the sql query again" which is back to scenario 1.

Comment: @David542 sqltabledependency is pushing the information on the client, without any need to reload it.  It would be up to you to setup it properly.   I tried to create a minimal showcase example where you would have to pick on the notification pushed.   I'm including, in edit, a complete example, via links.  Where you can see complete setup of a real-time chart being updated upon data change.

Answer (score 0):

I think question might be rooted in an issue with the client's graph and it's design requirements.

A "sales in the last hour" graph is both lacking information and hard to update.

Updates need to deduct sales as the "latest hour" progresses (1:05pm turns to 1:06pm) as well as add new sales.

In addition, the information might look exciting, but it provides very little information that marketing can use to improve sales (i.e., at which hours should more ads be added).

I would consider a 24 hour graph, or a 12 hour graph divided by actual hours.

This could simplify updates and would probably provide more useful metrics.

This way, updates to the graph are always additive, so no in-memory data-store is required (and the information is more actionable).

For example, every new sale could be published to a `"new_sale"` channel. The published sale data could include it's exact time.

This would allow subscribed clients to add new sales to the correct hour in the graph without ever invoking an additional database call and without requiring an in-memory data-store.